# With Fpm does not work no matter how many ways I try it (--with-fpm)

Tags: php, macos, ubuntu, nginx

I'm trying to install PHP with the FPM module and I simply cannot. I'm on Mac OS Big Sur

```
brew install php74 --with-fpm --with-debug --with-cgi --with-libmysql --with-homebrew-curl
```

And I get:

> Error: invalid option: --with-fpm

No matter how I format this I cannot get this to work. Is it not available anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it comes automatically. Installing "just" php74 by issuing `brew install php@7.4` will include the fpm.

From the homebrew docs:

> The php.ini and php-fpm.ini file can be found in:
> $(brew --prefix)/etc/php/7.4/

also included in here:
**https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula/php@7.4.json**

On my system it just works:

> To have launchd start php@7.4 now and restart at login:
> brew services start php@7.4
> Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
> php-fpm

After staring the FPM `brew services start php@7.4` its listening on port 9000

```
telnet localhost 9000
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'
```

Comment: But where is the fpm.sock file that nginx expects?

Comment: Mine is listing on port `9000` So use this in your nginx config or change the fpm-config located `/usr/local/etc/php/7.4/php-fpm.d`